# Why static array with length not initially defined don't result in compilation error in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have been coding for a while but C++ is pretty new to me.

I know that there are static and dynamic arrays in C++. Static arrays are assigned memory during the compile time and dynamic during runtime in heap.
And dynamic arrays are declared as:

```
data-type * variable = new data-type[value];
```

For eg:-

```
int*a = new int[n];
```

And static arrays are declared :

```
int a[n];   //where n already has value during the compilation time.
```

So, my question is-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
      int n;
      cin>>n;
      int a[n][n];  //static array
}
```

Why this code doesn't run in compilation error since the value of n is defined during runtime. So how can the static array with a variable n be defined during compilation?

Comment: Some compilers add [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) as an extension of the language. Don't use it though (or pointers and dynamic allocation), use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: The language is called C++. `cpp` is the C preprocessor.

Comment: How are you compiling your code?

Comment: I wish compilers were able to make an error for anything which at first seems to work but is a questionable design decision on the long run (even if only for being non-portable). I really wish. On the other hand, I might be out of a job then...

Comment: I am using `ideone.com` for the execution of this code.

Comment: Add `-Wall` to compiler flags.

Comment: @Surt what this Wall flag does..

Answer (score 1):

ideone.com uses g++ to compile C++ (this is mentioned in their FAQ).

The [gcc documentation says](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html):

> Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and **as an extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++**.

(Emphasis mine.)

In other words, this is a non-standard language extension supported by gcc.

Comment: If I understand [this](https://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#vla) correctly, clang supports them too, *"for compatibility with GNU C and C99 programs"*. Of course, they also point out that *"This extension is not permitted in standard C++"*.